# Why am I getting an error when creating a new news entry page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql

I am working with GraphQL and React and I have next post form code:

```html
const PostForm = props => {

  // set the default state of the form
  const [values, setValues] = useState();

  // update the state when a user types in the form
  const onChange = event => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Form
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          props.action({
            variables: {
              ...values
            }
          });
        }}
      >

      <label htmlFor="title">Title Post:</label>
      <input
        required
        type="text"
        id="title"
        name="title"
        placeholder="title"
        onChange={onChange}
      />

      <label htmlFor="category">Category Post:</label>
      <input
        required
        type="text"
        id="category"
        name="category"
        placeholder="category"
        onChange={onChange}
      />

        <TextArea
          required
          type="text"
          name="body"
          placeholder="Post content"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
      </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

This code I have in the new post page:

```html
const NEW_POST = gql`
  mutation createPost($title: String, $category: String, $body: String) {
    createPost(title: $title, category: $category, body: $body) {
      _id
        title
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        body
        author {
          name
        }
        comments{
          text
        }
      }
    }`;

const NewPost = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = 'NewPost - Notedly';
  });

  const [ data, { loading, error } ] = useMutation(NEW_POST, {
    onCompleted: data => {
      props.history.push(`posts/${data.createPost._id}`);
    }
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    {loading && <p> loading...</p>}
    {error && <p>Error saving the note</p>}
{console.log(data)}
      <PostForm action={data} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I have the following mutation code, for example:

```
mutation{
  createPost(title: "my jobs", category: "6251ef28413373118838bbdd", body: "smdbsdfsjns"){
    _id
    title
    category
    {catname}
    body
  }
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400"

Comment: We have no idea why the API responds with a 400 http error. The body of the response or the logs from the server should tell you, but we can't.

Comment: The response from the API should contain information about what is wrong with the data you passed to the mutation.

Comment: thanks to all. i found an error. it was inaccurate String! or String